# How to run python scripts and do CMD in Dockerfile for the docker container

Tags: python, docker, npm, dockerfile

I have an image with a custom Dockerfile. When I start the container, I want to run `CMD ["npm, "start"]` but right before that, I need to run three scripts.

I've tried:

1)putting the python scripts followed by npm start in a .sh script, and running `CMD ["script-location/script.sh"]`

2) calling `CMD ["script", "npm", "start"]`

none of this is working, and after the python scripts run, the container shuts down instead of running npm start and listening at a port. Not sure how to fix this.

the bash script I have is:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo starting to run runtime_properties...
python /var/first_script.py
echo finished runtime_properties

echo starting to run runtime_properties...
python /var/second_script.py
echo finished runtime_files

echo starting to run config-dns-props...
python /var/third_script.py
echo finishing config runtime files

echo starting to run npm start...
npm start
```

Comment: You say that the python scripts ran- so your shell script was successfully executed?  In that case the problem is your shell script- why not post that?

Comment: No, only the first line runs, `python first-script.py` it seems the other scripts don't do anything, and npm doesn't start but I'll update original post right now!

Comment: You see the first echo statement and nothing else, or you see all the echo statements?

Comment: aha doing ENTRYPOINT seems to have worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to run `ENTRYPOINT ["script-path/script.sh"]`